# Dividing and multiplying columns in mySQL

Tags: mysql, join, converters

This has been bugging me for some time i have following two tables:

```
Table: conv
---------------
id       cur     toEUR
--------------------------------------------
1       EUR       1
2       GBP       0.85
3       USD       1.32
--------------------------------------------

Table: itms
--------------
id       cur       price
--------------------------------------------
1       USD       5
2       USD      10
3       EUR       2.5
---------------------------------------------
```

Basically I need to divide the appropriate values...

```
SELECT itms.price/conv.toEUR 
  FROM itms
     , conv 
 where itms.cur=conv.cur
```

...from 'itms' with the ones from 'conv' and multiply by the value I want to convert to in 'conv'.
 Is this possible purely in SQL? I have attempted a few times, but I'm not sure what the best approach is.. 
 Any hints are appreciated!
 Best Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
select 
  i.id,
  c2.cur,
  i.price * c2.toEUR / c.toEur
from itms i
  join conv c on i.cur = c.cur
  join conv c2 on c2.cur = 'GBP'
order by i.id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e4d5/1)

Comment: @AndreasJarbol -- np, glad I could help!